# how to right click on item from Listbox and open menu on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i have Listbox with files in, i want to able to right click and open a menu like Delete in order to remove files from the Listbox.

currently i have this function after right click on item inside my Listbox

```
private void listBoxFiles_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

and i implement at XAML Delete menu after right click

```
          <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>                                                        
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

the function who delete file from my ListBox:

```
private void MenuItemDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    if (listBoxFiles.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    //string filePath = (listBoxFiles.SelectedItem).ToString();
    int index = listBoxFiles.SelectedIndex;
    listBoxFiles.Items.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 39):

You already have a context menu with your markup.

If you want to perform some operation, one of the ways is to check which item was clicked in the menu's Click function.
For example, you have the next listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="someListBox">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu>
             <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItemDelete_Click"/>
         </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>

    <ListBoxItem>...</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>...</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>...</ListBoxItem>

</ListBox>
```

And function may be next:

```
private void MenuItemDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (someListBox.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

    // Hypothetical function GetElement retrieves some element
    var element = GetElement(someListBox.SelectedIndex);

    // Hypothetical function DeleteElement
    DeleteElement(element);
}
```

**Updated 5 March 2012:**

Here is another variant of your listbox. You can add a context menu not to listbox but to the listbox items. For example:

```
<ListBox Name="someListBox" MouseDown="someListBox_MouseDown">
    <ListBox.Resources>

        <!--Defines a context menu-->
        <ContextMenu x:Key="MyElementMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItemDelete_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>

        <!--Sets a context menu for each ListBoxItem in the current ListBox-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
             <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MyElementMenu}"/>
        </Style>

    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBoxItem>...</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>...</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>...</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

1) This function will unsellect all items when you clicked on the empty space in the listbox:

```
private void someListBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    someListBox.UnselectAll();
}
```

2) When you click the lisboxt item, it is blue. When you right click the listbox item, it is still blue, but if a context menu appears, the listbox item becomes gray, maybe it is so because this item loses a focus.

3) Delete function works fine:

```
private void MenuItemDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (someListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    someListBox.Items.RemoveAt(someListBox.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: i want to add 3 functions in the menu so it's still necessary to check which item was clicked ? and i did not understand the last 2 lines in the function s MenuItemDelete_Click

Comment: i want to add 3 functions in the menu (each option in the menu will have different function) so it's still necessary to check which item was clicked ? and i did not understand the last 2 lines in the function s MenuItemDelete_Click

Comment: Because all list elements share a context menu, you should check which item was clicked. The last 2 lines are not necessary, i wrote them just to show some example. You should determine which element was clicked and perform some operations with that element.

Comment: If you want to retrieve a text value of clicked element you can write:
    `string elementText =((ListBoxItem)someListBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();`

Comment: Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.

Comment: it's OK now but i have another questions: 1. why each pressing on item in the Listbox change it's status from selected (color blue) to not selected and if file is selected and i press on an empty space on the Listbox the file remained selected ? 2. i implement function that if i press right click on item in the Listbox and in the menu press Delete the item removed from my List box but this happen only if the file not selected before, in mean if i press on item in the list box and than right click and remove the file remined in the Listbox and not deleted, please see my update

Comment: first thanks you for your help ! i think this way that the file remains in the listbox after he become blue (mouse down) and than right click and after that delete option chosen
its not normal behaviour, are you sure there is no way do delete files in this way ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't know what to suggest you. In my application elements are deleted in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

not need `listBoxFiles_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown`
when you wrote

```
<ListBox>
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
        </ListBox>
```

it is already working after right click

Comment: OK thanks, now how can i "catch" the file name (path) i clicked on ?

Comment: i want to add 3 functions in the menu (each option in the menu will have different function) so it's still necessary to check which item was clicked ? and i did not understand the last 2 lines in the function s MenuItemDelete_Click

Comment: Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.

Comment: it's OK now but i have another questions: 1. why each pressing on item in the Listbox change it's status from selected (color blue) to not selected and if file is selected and i press on an empty space on the Listbox the file remained selected ? 2. i implement function that if i press right click on item in the Listbox and in the menu press Delete the item removed from my List box but this happen only if the file not selected before, i mean if i press on item in the Listbox and than right click and remove the file remined in the Listbox and not deleted, please see my update